# Import error when importing wx on Apple silicon

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I have a Python 3.8 project that was created on a Intel Mac that I'm trying to get working on my Apple silicon M2 MacBook Pro.

wxPython installed fine using brew, but importing wx causes the following import error:

```
Python 3.11.2 (main, Feb 16 2023, 02:55:59) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wx/_core.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN10wxBoxSizer20InformFirstDirectionEiii'
```

I've tried re-installing wxPython clean, but didn't help.

Comment: I've got the same problem with Python 3.11.2 installed from the python.org binary on my M1 MacBook Air. Deleting 3.11.2 and installing 3.10.10 removed the error. So I'm inclined to believe this has to do with version 3.11.2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Installing python3@3.10 solved my issue. I guess wxPython isn't working with 3.11. Thanks!